# Find number of occurrence of a word in a cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the number of occurrence of a given word in a cell of string. What can be the possible formula used to calculate the occurrence?

Comment: Can you give some sample input and output? Do you need whole words?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `A1` has `fun fun no fun` and you want to know how many times "fun" occurrs, you can use this formula:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"fun","")))/LEN("fun")
```

Edit: Note that this may not be perfect, as it'll return `3` for `fun funky fun no`, instead of `2`.  You can work around this by adding spaces around the word you're looking for...then check for the first word in the cell to see if it matches what you want.  ...so I'd say this is a limited use-case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get your answer via a standard formula approach, try this UDF.  Drop it into a new module within the VBA editor.  Google "*how do I create a new module in excel VBA*" if you're not sure how to do that.

```
Public Function CountSpecificWord(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strWord As String, Optional ByVal bIgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As Long
    Application.Volatile

    Dim i As Long, strThisWord As String, arrWords() As String

    arrWords = Split(strText, " ")

    If bIgnoreCase Then strWord = UCase(strWord)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrWords)
        strThisWord = arrWords(i)
        If bIgnoreCase Then strThisWord = UCase(strThisWord)
        If strWord = strThisWord Then CountSpecificWord = CountSpecificWord + 1
    Next
End Function
```

There are 2 parameters ...

- **strText** - The text you are wanting to search within.
- **strWord** - The text you are wanting to search for.
- **bIgnoreCase** - Do you want the search to be case sensitive?  This is optional, default is false.

You can then use it in a cell ...

[image: Usage]

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count whole words only, this is a bit cumbersome but would work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))+1))-1)+1,LEN(A1)))="fun"))
```